# How to implement progress-bar in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ionic3

I have used ProgressBar-component from https://github.com/dnchia/ProgressBar-component, but getting error as shown in below image:

[image]

How to solve this error, please any reply as soon as possible.

see app.module.ts file:

[image]

Comment: Looks like the progress-bar component isn't being registered with Angular.

Comment: what is the solution for its?

Comment: show your app.module.ts file

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert, but there are plenty of potential reasons: the component isn't getting compiled into the bundle, it's not being added to your `@NgModule`, etc. It looks like the creator of this component just followed a tutorial to create it; try following along with [that tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-simple-progress-bar-component-in-ionic-2/).

Comment: @Karnan Muthukumar, please see the second image of app.module.ts file.

Comment: In app.module.ts file which component you are used progress bar. kindly tell then only i have to understand

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: iam updated my answer with example stackblitz i hope its solve your problem.

Comment: did you tried my answer?.

Comment: yes, i tried. solved error but not appears progress bar.

Comment: it is solved. thanks a lot @Karnan Muthukumar to give as soon your response.

Comment: pls upvote and mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was looking you have to add your progress bar in app.module.ts file,

Then only you have to use that progress bar.

```
import { ProgressBarComponent } from '../components/progress-bar/progress-bar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [  
    ProgressBarComponent
  ],

})
export class AppModule {}
```

here iam updated working stackblitz for you. you can use.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-progressbar-muthu-ewl6ag

home.html

```
  <progress-bar [progress]="loadProgress"></progress-bar>
```

home.ts

```
public loadProgress : number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    // Test interval to show the progress bar
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.loadProgress < 100)
        this.loadProgress += 1;
      else
        clearInterval(this.loadProgress);
    }, 50);
  }
```

index.html file,

```
<style>
  .progress-outer {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 10px 2%;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }

  .progress-inner {
    min-width: 15%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: green;
  }
      </style>
```

you can change this style wherever its your choice.

here is output screenshot,
[image]

I hope its solve your problem

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. I have a question, how can we use your code in order to make the same but for a countdown? For exemple, from 10% to 0%. The green bar does not go down. Do you have any idea? maybe CSS...